# How to use list in gradle build file?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have an external gradle file.

```
test = [
            ["testImplementation", "junit:junit:4.13.2"]
    ]

    list = []
    list.addAll(test)
```

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    list.each {
        if ($it[0].equals("testImplementation")) {
            testImplementation $it[1] 
        }
    }
}
```

But it's getting a syntax error, can you tell me the correct way to do it?

> Could not get unknown property '$it' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Try referencing the variable without the `$`.  The `$` token is only for when you're inside a String.

Comment: @User51 You're right.